# Can't add new columns inside function

Tags: r

I want to streamline my data import and add columns with IDs. If I do it manually, it works as it should. If I write a function, it doesn't work.

```
#Function
my_function <- function(experiment.ID, group.ID){

    df <- as.data.frame(c(0, 1, 2, 3))
    df$exp_ID     <- experiment.ID
    df$group_ID   <- group.ID
}
df_from_function <- my_function(experiment.ID = "A", group.ID = "group1")


#Manual
experiment.ID = "A"
group.ID = "group1"

df <- as.data.frame(c(0, 1, 2, 3))
df$exp_ID     <- experiment.ID
df$group_ID   <- group.ID

df_from_manual <- df
```

The first one returns a character only. The second one returns a data frame with appended columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function needs to actually _return_ the resulting data frame. Functions need inputs and outputs.

Comment: You need to return the new `df` from your function. If your last line is an assignment, it will only return the value used during that assignment (and will do so invisibly). Add a line with just `df` to the end of your function.

Comment: I see. I have another function that ends with `within(df, rm(column))` which consequently *returns* the df at the end. Hence I didn't notice the lack of a returned value until now.